# Split string at first space?

Tags: string-manipulation

How can I split a string at the first space character in it?

For example, "First I. Last, Jr." should become {"First","I. Last, Jr."}.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the third argument of `StringSplit` to split input string into at most 2 substrings:

```
str = "First I. Last, Jr.";

StringSplit[str, " ", 2]
```

> ```
> {"First", "I. Last, Jr."}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Using string pattern or regex

````
StringCases["First I. Last, Jr.",StartOfString~~Shortest[head___]~~" "~~Longest[tail___]~~EndOfString:>{head,tail}]

StringCases["First I. Last, Jr.",RegularExpression["^(\\S*?)(\\s)(.*)$"]:>{"$1","$3"}]

{{"First", "I. Last, Jr."}}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "First I. Last, Jr.";
```

Similar to what @Nasser suggested earlier with slightly different syntax:

```
{StringTake[str, # - 1],
   StringTake[str, {# + 1, StringLength@str}]
   } &@First@First@StringPosition[str, " "]
```

---

If one didn't know about the third argument:

```
{First@#, StringJoin@Rest@#} &@StringSplit[str, " "]
```

---

Using `StringCases`:

```
StringCases[str, 
 a : Shortest[___] ~~ " " ~~ b : __ :> Sequence @@ {a, b}]
```

---

Circuitous but more flexible:

```
SequenceReplace[
 Characters@str, {a__, " ", b__} :> 
  Sequence @@ {StringJoin@a, StringJoin@b}]
```

---

> {"First", "I. Last, Jr."}